# Question about axioms of an ordered field.

Tags: analysis, ordered-fields

I’m currently studying Introduction to Analysis by Ross. I wanted to ask if the either - or is an inclusive or exclusive disjunction in property O1 below. I believe this should just expressing the trichotomy of the reals, right?

[image]

Comment: The or is meant to be inclusive or as is the case universally in mathematics. This is expressing the idea that any two elements are comparable in this set. There are no incomparables as is sometimes the case in a partial order.

Comment: If a=b then they satisfy both inequalities. So I hope it is including.

Answer (score 0):

It's inclusive disjunction, i.e. that there can be $a\leq b$, $b\leq b$ or both. If we define the relation $<$ by the formula $a<b \iff a\leq b$ and $a\neq b$ then from O1 we get trichotomy: $a<b$, $a=b$ or $b<a$, which is easy to prove. Namely, take any $a,b$. Then either $a=b$ or $a\neq b$ (exclusive disjunction). If $a\neq b$ then we see from O1 that either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$ (exclusive so far). Since $a\neq b$ then either $a<b$ or $b<a$. Observe that if $a<b$ and $b<a$ then $a=b$, which is a contradiction. Therefore we get trichotomial exclusive disjunction.

Comment: This makes sense, I was trying to figure out how O1 was compatible with O2, but this cleared things up.